# Javascript filtrar array recursivamente

Tags: javascript, array, foreach, recursión, filtro

Tengo una lista:

```
const lista = [
  { numEmpleado: 1, responsable: 200 },
  { numEmpleado: 2, responsable: 201 },
  { numEmpleado: 3, responsable: 200 },
  { numEmpleado: 4, responsable: 201 },
  { numEmpleado: 5, responsable: 1 },
  { numEmpleado: 6, responsable: 1 },
  { numEmpleado: 7, responsable: 5 },
  { numEmpleado: 8, responsable: 7 },
];
```

parto de un empleado X con numEmpleado= 200. 
Necesito hacer un filtro recursivo de manera que me devuelva todos los elementos en lista cuyo responsable sea 200 y elementos que a su vez tengan como responsable alguno de ellos y así recursivamente.
En el ejemplo debería devolver los elementos:

```
const filtered = [
  { numEmpleado: 1, responsable: 200 },
  { numEmpleado: 3, responsable: 200 },
  { numEmpleado: 5, responsable: 1 },
  { numEmpleado: 6, responsable: 1 },
  { numEmpleado: 7, responsable: 5 },
  { numEmpleado: 8, responsable: 7 },
];
```

Tengo la función:

```
 getResp() {
    let filterResults = [];
    let filterAndPushResults = (numEmpleado) => {
        let empResp = this.state.employees.filter(
            (x) => x.responsable === numEmpleado
        );
        filterResults.push(...empResp);
        if (empResp.length > 0)
            empResp.forEach((item) => filterAndPushResults(item.numeroEmpleado));
    };
    filterAndPushResults(this.state.loggedUser.numeroEmpleado);
    return filterResults;
}
```

El array de filtro "this.state.employees" tiene unos 10000 elmentos. 
Al ejecutarlo me duelve el error: 
InternalError: "too much recursion"

¿Cómo puedo ejecutar el filtro recursivo?
Gracias

Comment: "parto de un empleado X con numEmpleado= 200"'. Podrías explicar más esta parte? Supongo que quieres obtener los empleados con el numEmpleado 200 y que su responsable también sea el 200?

Comment: quiero obtener los empleados cuyo responsable sea 200 que serían {numEmpleado = 1, responsable= 200}, {numEmpleado = 3, responsable= 200}] y de nuevo buscar los empleados cuyo responsables sea igual a alguno de los numEmpleado obtenidos y así sucesivamente

Answer (score 0):

Eso se debe a que estas creando un ciclo infinito de manera indirecta y javascript lo esta frenando al darse cuenta de esto, es infinito debido a que:

```
if (empResp.length > 0) empResp.forEach((item) => filterAndPushResults(item.numeroEmpleado));
```

Como vemos en esa parte estas llamando dentro de la funcion filterAndPushResults de nuevo a filterAndPushResults,  para solucionarlo simplemente no invoques este metodo dentro de el mismo con un ciclo foreach de nuevo...

Como dice el error eso es demasiada recursividad.

Answer (score 0):

te propongo el siguiente código.

```
 getRespWithNumber(numEmpleado, list) {
    let filterResults = [];
    let spliceIndex = [];
    if(list.length > 0){ // Break the recursivity
        // Añadimos los elementos
        for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            if(list[i].responsable === numEmpleado){
                filterResults.push(list[i]);
                spliceIndex.push(i); 
            }
        }
        // Los eliminamos de la lista
        spliceIndex.forEach(element => {
            list.splice(element ,1);
        });
        // Y llamamos recursivamente con los elementos insertados
        for(let j = 0; j < spliceIndex.length; j++){  // Usamos spliceIndex.length porque son los primeros elementos de la lista, y los insertados en esta iteración, los siguientes vienen de llamar recursivamente a la función
            filterResults = filterResults.concat(getRespWithNumber(filterResults[j].numEmpleado, list));
        }
    }
    return filterResults;
}
```

Un saludo.